# Generic object/class type to pass back to httppost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a method that passes back my viewmodel from a view as such in my post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(daViewModel model)
{
    string whatever = model.Name;
    int id = model.Id;
    return View();
}
```

What type of object get's passed back to my controller method on the post (is my viewmodel wrapped in an httppost type of class?) Is there a generic/type that I can pass such as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadFiles(object model)
{
    // cast my daViewModel from object model as passed in???
    string whatever = model.Name;
    int id = model.Id;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get your questions here, but the data type of your class is defined by you, ModelBinder will bind data from form values or query strings to your model class. You can create your own model binder class to work with specific model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a `FormCollection` object:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadFiles(FormCollection collection)
{
    // if you want to extract properties directly:
    string whatever = collection["Name"];
    int id = int.Parse(collection["Id"]);

    // if you want to convert the collection to your model:
    SomeModel model;
    TryUpdateModel(model, collection);

    return View();
}
```

The `TryUpdateModel` method returns a boolean. If it succeeds in updating the model it will return true, otherwise it will return false. The form values being passed in should match the property names of your model.

If you're asking what model gets passed back when you call `return View()` then the answer to that is nothing unless you tell it to. There is an overload on the `View()` method which takes in a model:

```
return View(model);
```

You should be returning the type that the View expects to see. If you defined your view as having a model of `Foo` then you better return a `Foo` in your controller.

Comment: Thx!  What if I have a complex object collection in my view model?  IEnumerable<MyComplexObject> myObects.  ?  Can I still map that to ["myObjects"] and get that collection accordingly from the form collection?  Also, will it map in the TryUpdateModel?

Comment: @Mariah if your form data is named correctly it will be able to update an enumerable (or list/array, etc) just fine.